# How to set the value of context in the object tag of a jsp with struts 1

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I need to know how to establish, in full context object tag of a jsp, because I'm getting fixed data, the jsp code is as follows:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="http://localhost:8080/JasperStruts/report.do?dispatch=reports" width="80%" height="650"></object>
```

But instead of appearing `"http: //localhost:8080/"` i need appears according to where the application is run, the link is within the same system that is running.

i am using Struts 1

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data about path always are in the request, then you have to call `request.getContextPath`, in your case, the code would be something like this:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/JasperStruts/report.do?dispatch=reports" width="80%" height="650"></object>
```

See this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29

I hope this information help you.

Good luck =D

Comment: thanks !! that works, but do not break any rules? Is it worth putting scriptlet code when needed?

Comment: yeah, you right, but it's only when it's neccesary, because you can make spaghetti code (this term is used in Mexico, I don't know if this is called same in another places :P) and it would be difficult to maintain.

Comment: I suggest you try using the <c:url> JSTL tag insted. It will correctly handle the context root and you avoid scriptlets. And yeah, scriptlets are fine if used for trivial things, but can and should be avoided almost always, using custom tags or often just JSTL.

Comment: yes hmrojas.p in mexico used the term "chile con huevo" im Mexican too.